# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/rain'

Tags: jupyter-notebook

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/rain'

remedy for my problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.